# How to modify all elements except the current one when iterating

Tags: java, collections

I have list of Comments that contains a list of Tags.

I want to iterate over my list of Comments, and if one comment has a Tag DEPRECATE_OTHERS, I want to add a tag DEPRECATED to ALL other comments.

So far I've been able to come up with a too cluttered solution, but I'm wondering if there's some facility that could help me make it cleaner:

```
    for (int i = 0; i < comments.size(); i++) {
        Comment comment = comments.get(i);
        for (Tag tag : comment.getTags()) {
            if(MyEnum.DEPRECATE_OTHERS.equals(tag)) {
                for(int j = 0; j < comments.size(); j++) {
                    if(j != i) {
                        comments.get(j).getTags().add(MyEnum.DEPRECATED)
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

OBS: I might have multiple DEPRECATE_OTHERS and I'd like to add multiple DEPRECATED flags in that case

Comment: I'm not sure I understand now. Let's say two comments have `DEPRECATE_OTHERS`. Should all the other comments get two `DEPRECATED` tags, and these get one each? Or should comments that have `DEPRECATE_OTHERS` never have a `DEPRECATED` tag?

Comment: For each DEPRECATE_OTHERS I find, I have to add a DEPRECATED to all other tags. The reason is my Tag type is more complex than I described in the exercise.

Comment: if two comments (A, B) have DEPRECATE_OTHERS they will have the DEPRECATED tag or not? (because A DEPRECATE_OTHERS makes the B DEPRECATED, same for the B to A)

Comment: Sounds like my answer might work then.

Comment: Yes Marco, you're correct.

Comment: Dave, in your second forEach, I don't see how I would be getting only the other comments. It would iterate again through all comments and that's not what I'm expecting.

Comment: What you except? You don't want to iterate over all comments? You want to iterate from 0 to COMMENT_WITH_DEPRECATE_OTHERS_TAG? Or you want to avoid the second for?

Answer (score 2):

There are a few methods you could use to simplify this code. Using for each iteration, `Collection.contains()` and object equality you could get it down to this:

```
for (Comment comment : comments) {
    if(comment.getTags().contains(MyEnum.DEPRECATE_OTHERS))) {
        for (Comment otherComment : comments) {
            if (otherComment != comment) {
                otherComment.getTags().add(MyEnum.DEPRECATED)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As Adam says, two separate iterations would be neater still.

Comment: Yours looks much nicer, so I'm gonna vote it up. My only reasoning behind the double loop is that in the BEST CASE complexity, the very first comment has the deprecate others tag, and its the only one. In that case only one complete iteration would be needed.

Answer (score 0):

set a flag, something like `deprecate_others_id = -1;`
When you find a DEPRECATE_OTHERS tag, set that variable to the index, and while that var is not -1, set each tag to DEPRECATE_OTHERS. At the end of your iteration, start a new loop from the beginning which iterates until it reaches `deprecate_others_id`, marking all those along the way.

This makes use of the fact you are currently iterating anyway, only making you circle back for the tags before the one which initiated `Deprecate_Others`

```
int deprecate_others_id = -1;
int numtags = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < comments.size(); i++) {
    Comment comment = comments.get(i);
    if(deprecate_others_id != -1){
        while(comment.getNumberofDepTags < numtags){
           comment.addTag(DEPRECATED);
        }
    }
    for (Tag tag : comment.getTags()) {
        if(MyEnum.DEPRECATE_OTHERS.equals(tag)) {
            deprecate_others_id = Math.max(deprecate_others_id,i);
        }
    }
}
if(deprecate_others_id != -1){
    for(int i=0; i<deprecate_others_id; i++){
      Comment comment = comments.get(i);
      while(comment.getNumberofDepTags < numtags){
           comment.addTag(DEPRECATED);
      }
    }
}
```

Comment: Agree, I had thought about it, the issue is I might have multiple DEPRECATE_OTHERS and I'd like to add multiple DEPRECATED flags in that case. (my tag structure is more complex than a String).

Comment: but if you are adding DEPRECATED to every other comment, then this still works. Just store the `Math.max()` of the ids and the number of `DEPRECATED` tags to add. In the second loop, iterate to the max id, adding tags until each comment has `numtags` number of DEPRECATED tags.